# How to apply right hand rule to determine the direction of Torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, vectors, torque

I have just started out rotational dynamics but after solving a few questions I found that most of the answers are coming to be wrong because I could not determine the direction of torque correctly.  I referred to a book where it has been said

> Curl the fingers of right hand from the direction of r into the direction of F,  outstretched thumb points in the direction of the torque

Now I tried applying this. Suddenly I realised r (distance) is a vector quantity but while solving questions I can take r in any direction. But In this way the results coming , definately differ from each other.  That's why I am a little bit confused about the direction of r. Specially when I have to conserve the torque about a point,  I become confused with the signs in the torque balance equation.

Comment: -1 Have you tried googling your question title?

Answer (score 1):

The direction of 'r' is taken from the origin/point of observation. Hence, if you are looking at a point 'B' from point 'A', the direction of 'r' is from 'A' to 'B'. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> but while solving questions I can take r in any direction

No, you can't. $\vec r$ is from the hinge (point of rotation) to the point where the force acts.

Think of a simple wrench. You pull at the end of it with a force $\vec F$ and $\vec r$ is along the shaft. When you have a force and know the hinge point (rotation centre), then you always have a fixed set of vectors to do the right-hand-rule on.